# ezdxf how to extract the tags associated with text in the block layout

Tags: python, cad, dxf, dxflib

How to extract the tag associated with the text value from dxf block layout.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: drawing file with a format layout]

For example, TITLE is the header that comes as part of drawing format layout, DESC is the text tag associated with the TITLE Content "BASE". How can I extract the DESC (&TITLE) with TITLE Content.

I tried viewing the dxf file in notepad but doesn't have these tag entries. Is there a way to extract not only the text but also the associated tag?

Answer (score 3):

As the name *ezdxf* already says, ezdxf works with DXF files not with DWG or DRW files, unlike DXF, is DWG an undocumented binary encoded AutoCAD file format.

Maybe you can export your files as DXF files to process them with ezdxf:

Scenario 1, ATTRIB attached to block reference INSERT:

```
doc = ezdxf.readfile('YourFile.dxf')
msp = doc.modelspace()
# block reference attributes (tags) are stored in the INSERT entity
for insert in msp.query('INSERT')
    print(str(insert))
    for attrib in insert.attribs():
        print("Tag: {}, Value: {}".format(attrib.dxf.tag, attrib.dxf.text))
```

Scenario 2, ATTRIB, MTEXT or TEXT as standalone entity in modelspace or paperspace:

```
msp = doc.modelspace()
# or getting paperspace:
# psp = doc.layout('TabName')
# search for ATTRIB entities
for attrib in msp.query('ATTRIB')
    print("Tag: {}, Value: {}".format(attrib.dxf.tag, attrib.dxf.text))
# search for MTEXT entities
for mtext in msp.query('MTEXT')
    print("MTEXT content: {}".format(mtext.text)
for text in msp.query('TEXT')
    print("TEXT content: {}".format(text.dxf.text)
```

Scenario 3, entities located in BLOCK definitions:

```
for block in doc.blocks:
    print('searching in BLOCK definition {}'.format(block.name))
    # search for ATTRIB entities (or MTEXT and TEXT see above)
    for attrib in block.query('ATTRIB')
        print("Tag: {}, Value: {}".format(attrib.dxf.tag, attrib.dxf.text))
    # or like scenarion 1, search for INSERT with attached ATTRIB
    for insert in block.query('INSERT'):
        for attrib in insert.attribs()
            print("Tag: {}, Value: {}".format(attrib.dxf.tag, attrib.dxf.text))
```

Comment: thanks mozman for response...., however the above code prints just the text INSERT(#2EA) not the attributes. For your information, DXF structure is like this....The keyword TITLE appears under section ENTITIES -> IMAGE-> MTEXT. The Keyword BASE appears under section BLOCK->*T5 ->MTEXT, however no 'DESC' keyword found anywhere.

Comment: added some other possible scenarios to search for data, in your drawing the attributes are stored as simple MTEXT entities and not as ATTRIBs, 1. is located in  modelspace, 2. is located in an anonymous block called *T5, and the 3. seem to be a FIELD which is not supported by ezdxf, because lack of sufficient documentation by Autodesk

Comment: I am looking for a way to correlate "TITLE" and "BASE" and extract both the values printed next to each other in my output, the above scenarios are helpful to get the individual values as separate MTEXT context but not in associated form. please suggest.

Comment: I don't think there is binding between "Title" and "Base", they are text entities just located nearby. You could program a solution for exact this case, but it would only work for drawings with the exact same structure. For more help I would need the DXF file.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are new to ezdxf (like me), it took me a while to realise that on scenario 2 above, the .get_text() method in MTEXT has been replaced with .text since ezdxfVersion 0.10 released on 2019-09-01.

Therefore, I had to replace the following code in scenario 2 above:

```
# search for MTEXT entities
for mtext in msp.query('MTEXT')
print("MTEXT content: {}".format(mtext.get_text())
```

with the following:

```
# search for MTEXT entities
for mtext in msp.query('MTEXT')
print("MTEXT content: {}".format(mtext.text)
```

Other than that, the code from mozman worked great to extract the tags associated with text in layouts (msp or psp).